# Add two events in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I added two jQuery events, the second jQuery event is not triggering. What might be the issue? Here is my code :

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({

            events: function() {
                $('#couponcheck2').click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $('#couponcheck').empty();
                        $('#couponcheck').append('<div class="col-xs-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="enterCoupon"></div>');
                        $('#couponcheck').append('<div class="col-xs-8"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="couponbutton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Apply</button></div>');
                    }),
                    $('#signupbutton').click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log("in sec 2")
                        $('#section2').prepend('<h4 class="panel-title" data-parent="#accordion"data-target="#collapseTwo" data-toggle="collapse">')
                    });
            },
```

......... // code

Comment: signupbutton id you added dymanically ah???

Comment: @JqueryKing Yes. I dynamically added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a much nicer way to handle events in backbone:

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({

        events: {
            'click #couponcheck2': 'checkCoupon',
            'click #signupbutton' : 'signUp'
        },

        checkCoupon: function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $('#couponcheck').empty();
              $('#couponcheck').append('<div class="col-xs-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="enterCoupon"></div>');
              $('#couponcheck').append('<div class="col-xs-8"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="couponbutton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Apply</button></div>');
         },

         signUp: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("in sec 2");
                $('#section2').prepend('<h4 class="panel-title" data-parent="#accordion"data-target="#collapseTwo" data-toggle="collapse">');
         }
...
```

Answer (score 5):

That is not the way to use the events hash on a backbone view.

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({

events: {
 "click #couponncheck2": function(e) {
   // code goes here
}
```

Comment: This is not valid Javascript. I think you meant "events: {" instead of "events: function() {", which is indeed a proper way of declaring the events hash.

Comment: You're right. I took that out the extra `function ()`

Answer (score 2):

Use **Event delegation** for dynamically created elements in the DOM

```
 $(document).on('click', '#signupbutton', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("in sec 2")
    $('#section2').prepend('<h4 class="panel-title" data-parent="#accordion"data-target="#collapseTwo" data-toggle="collapse">')
  });
```